# toy web service on Eclipse- trouble with glassfish4 server

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-4, eclipse-jee

I am new to Java EE, and am trying to learn how to create a web service. I followed the instructions given at this link- http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Implementing_a_Simple_Web_Service.pdf to create a simple Hello World web service. I got into trouble when trying to get Eclipse to start the glassfish4 server. I get the error shown below-
I am not sure what ${sunappserver.rootdirectory} means and how it is defined. Much appreciate anyone who can help me understand this and get it working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your glassfish installation. This file contains lots of configuration details. Your Exception means it is missing! Maybe there is a backup called domain.xml.bak in the same directory.

Mine is in /usr/local/glassfish4_1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml